# Constructing a function with given values.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was working on a problem: "Construct a monic square polynomial P(x) such that P(3)=5, P(−1)=2." I tried to use the given values to make a system of equations, 5=9a+3b+c and 2=a-b+c, but I was unsuccessful in my attempts. Does anyone understand how to solve this?

Comment: At least write down the system of equation you have and explain why you failed.

Comment: Does "square polynomial" mean quadratic polynomial? In any case "monic" means "with leading coefficient $1$". Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 2):

There should only be two unknowns:   $x^2+bx+c$ would be a monic quadratic polynomial.   $a=1$.

Then you get two equations in two unknowns: $3^2+3\cdot b+c=5\implies 3b+c=-4$.

Next $(-1)^2-b+c=2\implies-b+c=1$.

Now $c=1+b$ and so$3b+1+b=-4\implies b=-5/4$.

Finally, $c=-1/4$.  So we get $x^2-5/4x-1/4$.